# Pandas - Writing string values to a Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have strings stored in 2 variables. I am trying to have this added to an empty Dataframe.

```
variable1 = abc
variable2 = def


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['action'])
```

I am not sure how to have these two variables added to Dataframe df in column labelled `action`.

Expected output:

```
action
abc
def
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass values to list in `DataFrame` constructor:

```
variable1 = 'abc'
variable2 = 'def'

df = pd.DataFrame([variable1, variable2], columns=['action'])
```

Or use dictionary with list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'action': [variable1, variable2]})

print (df)
  action
0    abc
1    def
```